# Não consigo colocar um botão no centro da tela. Este é o codigo em html/css

Tags: html, css

HTML:

Universo.2.0

## Hello World!

```
<div class="img">
<img src="image/filme-de-terror.png" alt="img">
</div>

<div class="btn">
<button class="btn" type="submit">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Entrar</a>
</button>
</div>
```

Css:

body{
overflow: hidden;
background-image: url('image/filme-de-terror.png');
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.h1{
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
top: 150px;
width: 450px;
line-height:0px;
height: 0px;

}

.img{
display: flex;
width:101%;

}

.btn{
display: flex;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}

Answer (score -2, accepted):

tente dessa maneira aqui.

body{ overflow: hidden; background-image: url('image/filme-de-terror.png');  }

.h1{ position: absolute; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); color: #fff; text-align: center; top: 150px; width: 450px; line-height:0px; height: 0px;

}

.img{ display: flex; width:101%;

}

.btn{ display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}

```
     <div class="btn">
     <img src="image/filme-de-terror.png" alt="img"><br>
     <button  type="submit">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" 
      role="button">Entrar</a>
     </button>
     </div>
```

O que eu fiz, foi juntar a imagem e o botão em uma div só, e usar uma class para os dois.... espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, porém o botão ficou na parte inferior. E não no meio da img. entendeu? Mas já ajudou bastante com esse code aí. vl2

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).